# Toll Like Receptors Vs Toll Receptors

Tags: immunology, development, receptor, drosophila, transcription-factor

What are the major differences between them, apart from one being in humans and other in *Drosophilla*?

Answer (score 2):

In *Drosophila*, Toll receptors are used during embryonic development as well as innate immunity. See [The Drosophila Toll Signaling Pathway](http://www.jimmunol.org/content/186/2/649.long) by Valance, et. al.

[Toll-like Receptors](http://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/toll-like-receptors-sensors-that-detect-infection-14396559) are pattern recognition receptors found in organisms other than *Drosophila* that recognize common motifs found on pathogens.

Toll receptors were first discovered in Drosophila and orthologous receptors were then found in many other organisms, not only Human. Both will transduce signaling and will lead to transcription of genes.